# Panorama IDs of All Street View Panoramas in Area (Street View Image API)

Tags: google-maps, google-api, google-street-view

I've been working on a novel use of the [Google Street View Image API](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/streetview/), but I keep running up against limitations in my dataset. Specifically, I'm interested in downloading parts of every Street View panorama in a given bounded geographical area, but I can't find a good way to obtain a list of the panoramas in that area first.

What I've been doing so far is to call `streetview/metadata` using a whole bunch of co-ordinates that are regularly placed (e.g. on a 1m grid), and then de-duplicating the returned panorama IDs. This is obviously sub-optimal, as it requires a huge number of network calls and is still prone to missing panoramas.

Does anyone have any better ideas? Is there another endpoint that I don't know about that I could use, or some workaround that would enable the retrieval of multiple panorama IDs at once?

Comment: Hi, I'm stuck in the same, did you figure out how?

Comment: @Sebastian Lenartowicz  I am all so stuck in same.Have You fine any solution for this

Comment: @NarenderReddy No, unfortunately not. I ended up taking the brute-force approach described in the original question.